# Bad mazal of Tisha B'AV

Tags: tisha-bav

Does Tisha B'AV actually have a bad mazal? As in, did bad things happen on this and related days and will they continue to happen? Or is it just in the past that calamity struck our people?
Why is aryeh (Leo) — the zodiac of the month of Av bad ?

Comment: A year after the exodus from Egypt, Bnei Yisrael sent spies to scout out the land. The spies reported bad tidings about Israel, and therefore Bnei Yisrael cried. That night was tisha bav. Gd said “since you cried for no reason, on this night I will give you a reason to cry for generations.” As we see throughout history, many particularly bad things have happened on this day

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4080908/jewish/Avoiding-Danger-During-the-9-Days.htm

Comment: Typically, Tishah Be'Av doesn't have a bad mazal, it has a very good mazal, and is a day we expect *mashiach* could come. Just that the mazal of Tishah Be'Av has been inverted, currently.